# Run-time check failure #2 - stack around the variable original_block was corrupted

Tags: c, runtime-error, visual-studio-2015

I'm afraid that this question has been asked before, and i sort of get why it's giving me this error, but I honestly cannot find exactly why. I wish you could help me with this guys?

I have to make the DES algorithm for my class, and i've already made the first step, and it works only when the text it's not too long. For some reason when i try to type a really long text it give me this error. Here's my code:

A structure where i store all the 64 bit blocks.

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    unsigned char *block[8];
}Blocks64;
```

The function that i use to add a 64 bit block (unsigned char[8])

```
void add_64bBlock(Blocks64 *block, char *value) {
    int i;
    block->block[block->size] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        block->block[block->size][i] = '\x0';
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        block->block[block->size][i] = value[i];
    }
    block->size++;
}
```

and the function for the first expantion:

```
Blocks64 expansionI(char *plain) {
    Blocks64 original_block;//Estructura para bloques del texto plano
    Blocks64 expanded_block;//Estructura para el texto ya expandido de expansionI
    int total_blocks;//Bloques totales
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    unsigned char byte[8];//bloque de 64 bits auxiliar

    //Cálculo del total de Bloques
    total_blocks = ceil(strlen(plain) / 8.0);
    init_64bBlock(&original_block);
    init_64bBlock(&expanded_block);
    printf("bloques: %d\n", total_blocks);

    //Pasar el texto plano a bloques en la estructura
    for (i = 0; i<total_blocks; i++) {
        init_byte(byte);
        for (j = 0; j<8; j++) {
            if(plain[(j + (i * 8))] == '\x0')
                j = 8;
            else
                byte[j] = plain[(j + (i * 8))];
        }
        add_64bBlock(&original_block, byte);
        //add_64bBlock_null(&expanded_block);
    }

    //Propósitos de Debuggeo
    for (i = 0; i<total_blocks; i++) {
        printf("Bloque %d\n",i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d.- %c - %d - ", j, get_64bBlock(&original_block, i)[j], get_64bBlock(&original_block, i)[j]);
            printbinchar(get_64bBlock(&original_block, i)[j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < total_blocks; i++) {
        init_byte(byte);
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                if ((get_64bBlock_char(&original_block, i, k) & (1 << 6 - (j * 2))) > 0) {
                    byte[j] = byte[j] | (1 << k);
                }
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                if ((get_64bBlock_char(&original_block, i, k) & (1 << 7 - (j * 2))) > 0) {
                    byte[j+4] = byte[j+4] | (1 << k);
                }
            }
        }
        add_64bBlock(&expanded_block,byte);
    }
    //Debuggeo
    printf("---------------\n");
    for (i = 0; i < total_blocks; i++) {
        printf("El bloque %d\n",i);
        printf("L0:\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%d.- %c - %d - ", j, get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j), get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j));
            printbinchar(get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j));
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("R0:\n");
        for (j = 4; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("%d.- %c - %d - ", j, get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j), get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j));
            printbinchar(get_64bBlock_char(&expanded_block, i, j));
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return expanded_block;
}
```

what's really weird is that it gives me the error and it halts, but when i check the window, the first expansion it's complete and correct. I don't really know what's going on. I tried freeing the chars inside the struct, but it's giving me an error. Any help would be REALLY appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, i found that the error occurs when i type more than 64 leters (512 bits).

Comment: Why do you `block->block[block->size] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char));` malloc() a single unsigned char, when you want to `for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        block->block[block->size][i] = '\x0';
    }` access at least eight of them?

Comment: You know what @EOF, you're right... that was exactly that i was noticing. Let me check maybe that's the problem.

Comment: What do you sugest? I tryed the following:
' block->block[block->size] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 8);' and did not work. Maybe i'm just too tired haha. Any ideas? @EOF

Comment: Sure. Get a debugger. Compile with `address sanitizer` if you've got gcc or clang. Run under `valgind`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio because GCC was giving me Errors in Windows 8. But to be honest i didn't look in a lot of places. You have any information regarding GCC and Windows 8?

Comment: You are simply accessing an array out of bounds somewhere. And yes, the `malloc(sizeof(unsigned char))` statement is complete nonsense. It's point to allocate one byte of memory. BTW you mention " GCC was giving me Errors in Windows 8". Do you mean compilation errors or runtime errors ? Which errors ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz a complete nonsense? You mean like i shouldn't use it at all? Because for some reason in my mind `malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 8)` sounds like it should do the trick, Unless i'm using it incorrectly.

Comment: @HectorHammett try that and get back to us. BTW char size is `1` so you can write `malloc(8)`.

Comment: I didn't look into it in details, but allocating one byte if pointless. The pointer to your byte takes already 4 bytes (or even 8 bytes on  64 bit system). So instead of having a _pointer_ to your single byte you could just have that sigle byte in your structure. But for sure one of your array indexes is out of bounds somewhere.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tryed that and still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys, i wasn't able to fix the problem. So i took a different approach and now it's working.

I've changed the structurue to this:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    unsigned char *block;
}Blocks64;
```

And i changed the function to initialize the structure, but now i also add how many blocks i'll use, so first i calculate how many 64bit blocks (8 unsigned chars) i'm gonna need:

```
void init_64bBlock(Blocks64 *block,int total) {
    block->size = 0;
    block->capacity = total;
    block->block = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * (8 * total));
}
```

and use it right here:

```
total_blocks = ceil(strlen(plain) / 8.0);
init_64bBlock(&original_block,total_blocks);
init_64bBlock(&expanded_block,total_blocks);
```

Now it's working. Thank you very much for your help!